# What is the Laurent series of the complex absolute value?

Tags: complex-analysis, absolute-value, laurent-series

What is the Laurent series of the function $f(z) = |z|$? It seems to be ill defined at $z=0$. Are there any other expansion techniques applicable for this function at $z=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't even holomorphic, nor is any non-constant real valued function. One easy way to see this is that if $f$ is holomorphic, then $$\left.\frac{d}{dt}f(z+tw)\right|_{t=0}=f'(z)w,$$
and if $f'(z)=0$ you can always pick $w$ so that $f'(z)w\notin\mathbb{R}$.

As for other expansion techniques, this is such a simple function, what need is there for any fancy expansions?

Comment: "What need is there for a fancy expansion?" There was a physics question about the zero point fluctuations of a coupled system of harmonic oscillators which is apparently unsolvable, where the Hamiltonian is similar to the one asked here.    http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/94143/zero-point-oscillations-for-a-harmonic-oscillator-with-a-square-root-in-the-hami

Answer (score 1):

For Laurent series, you need holomorphicity in an annulus, but you do not have this. For suppose to the contrary that $f$ were holomorphic in some open set. Then, $f^2 = z\bar{z}$ would be holomorphic in the same open set. But if you take the partial with respect to $\bar{z}$, then you get $z$, which is not identically 0 in any open set.

Comment: It's a fine answer, except I think it's pitched at the wrong level: I very much suspect that the OP won't know what $\partial f/\partial\bar z$ is.

Comment: Amusingly, this was actually the first thing I learned in my complex analysis course. But I suppose different courses will have different approaches.

Comment: Right; I never learned about it until some graduate level course.

Comment: Good answer. I don't think that it is on wrong level because the proof need no advanced topics.Most undergraduate books will indicate that or leave it as an exercise. It is even enough to use the CR equations to prove that the function must be $0$ for analyticity.